# What's the shortest distance between any two non-parallel line( segment)s?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

OK, so, I'm a noob by the way but anyway I just need a formula that can give the shortest distance between any two line( segment)s AB and CD. So basically you want nine variables:

AX, AY, BX, BY, CX, CY, DX, DY, L
(we're gonna use L to get my answer)

&ltsmall&rtspoiler: I'm going to use that formula to do line collision testing&lt/small&rt

OK, so my question got put on hold because

"**This question is missing context or other details:** Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc." – Lee David Chung Lin, Cesareo, John B, José Carlos Santos

I have no idea what to say sooooooo... um... did you read the spoilers? The thing was a maths problem so I wanted to get some way to know how to get the value but of course I wasn't competent enough to do it by myself. By the way I can only really start testing my program decently when I get to know. Uuuuuuuuummm...hmm, what else do I say... What's the difference between "B&M" and "why the question is interesting/important"? Well...because I don't want a circle crossing a line without touching it by moving too fast between frames so I want it's collision thing to be a line. Is that enough?

Comment: well there's the part where we did it but instead we're comparing only a point to a line

Comment: Do the two segments line in a common plane? Is it assumed that the segments do not intersect? And what are X, and Y? Is L the sought answer?

Comment: Yes; no (of course if they intersect the answer is 0 but it should still work/be valid for intersecting lines, I guess); the axes; yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is quite nice.  Let $x$ be a point, and $L$ be a line segment.  Then let's denote the minimum distance between a point and a line segment by $dist(x,L)$.

> The smallest distance between 2 (non-intersecting) line segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ is $$ min( \,\, dist(A, \overline{CD}),dist(B,\overline{CD}),dist(C,\overline{AB}),dist(D,\overline{AB}) \,\, ) $$But before applying this, we need to make sure the lines don't intersect. To check this: (work in progress)

Judging by your comments, you know how to find distance from point to a line? So then we are done

Comment: cool I'll see if it works

Comment: wait, "dab"? lol

Comment: My bad, the case where the lines intersect needs to be excluded, still working on that..

Comment: But we already know if they intersect the shortest distance is 0.

Comment: My min formula will not be zero if the line segments form a "cross" shape, draw a picture and you'll see.  We need a way to catch that case.  So "If intersect, then output 0.  Else, output min( d,d,d,d )"

Comment: The 2 line segments are in a common plane (it is a 2D problem)

Comment: Also remains to discuss how you get the distance of a point to a segment.

Comment: OP already did that (it looks like in the comments)

Comment: @NazimJ okay, if this is a 2d-problem, then this formula should  work.

Comment: Mh, point/line or point/segment ? The confusion is frequent.

Comment: @NazimJ: haha, I would have bet: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3175832/65203

Answer (score 2):

This is not a so easy problem due to multiple configurations, but it can be tamed. The shortest distance can be between two endpoints, between an endpoint and a segment, or even zero.

A key property is that if the segments do not intersect, then the endpoints of one of the segments lie on the same side of the other. The shortest distance will occur between the endpoint of the first segment closest to the line of support of the other segment, as show on the figure. This reduces the segment/segment problem to a point/segment one.

Now a segment defines three regions of the plane, such that an external point is closer to one of its endpoints or to the segment.

[image]

For best convenience, we can transform a segment $z_az_b$ so that it maps to $(0,0)-(1,0)$, by a combination of translation, rotation and scaling. This is readily expressed using complex numbers and corresponds to a transformation of the form

$$w=pz+q.$$

The complex coefficients $p,q$ are obtained by solving the easy system

$$\begin{cases}pz_a+q=0,\\pz_b+q=1.\end{cases}$$

So here is the outline of an algorithm:

- transform $ab$ to $01$ and compute $w_c,w_d$;
- transform $cd$ to $01$ and compute $w_a,w_b$;
- if the ordinates (imaginary parts) of $w_a,w_b$ and $w_c,w_d$ differ in sign for both pairs, the segments intersect; return $0$;
- otherwise choose a segment such that its ordinates do not differ in sign, let $w_aw_b$;
- consider the endpoint with the smallest absolute ordinate, let $w_a$;
- if the abscissa (real part) of $w_a$ is negative, return $|w_a|$;
- if the abscissa of $w_a$ exceeds $1$, return $|w_a-1|$;
- otherwise, return the absolute ordinate of $a$, $|\Im w_a|$.

Caution: as the distance computation is performed on the normalized segment, one needs to compensate by dividing by $|p|$.

---

**Technical note:**

You can follow the same principle without using the reduction transformation nor complex numbers. The comparison of the imaginary parts (ordinates) is in fact a comparison of the algebraic distances to the line of support. And the abscissas correspond to the algebraic distances to the orthogonals by the endpoints.

So there are alternative ways to cast the equations, but the principle of the discussion remains.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna read this.

Comment: 5 seconds later...<br>How the heck do I transform the lines based on their positions for starters?

Comment: 15 seconds later...<br>Does "$w$" mean "width" or something?

Comment: 5 minutes later...<br>(google searches) Does "$I$" mean the imaginary part? That doesn't make sense since you're talking about the real number...

Comment: 5:30 minutes later...<br>So we didn't have to transform or use complex numbers at all? I mean, I was going to use two numbers since my thing doesn't support natively complex numbers but am I wasting my time?

Comment: 6 minutes later...<br>Can I have a diagra--WAAAAAAAIIIIITTTT AM I breaking any rules by spamming comments? Sigh.

Comment: I'm missing valuable information necessary to know and process valuable information necessary to create a code that allows me to create a collision thingy.

Comment: Wait...$I$... Come on, why did I paste it and get "I" but it doesn't render that way now?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function `closest_point(A,B,D)` that returns the closest point on line segment AB to D. Then I think that if you just apply that function to all four points, at worst you'll get a numerical solution, and at best it will terminate. In Python:

```
import math

def distance_squared(A,B):
   return (A[0]-B[0])**2+(A[1]-B[1])**2

def line_segment_distance(A,B,C,D, epsilon, max_iterations):
    for i in range(max_iterations):
             A2 = closest_point(C,D,A)
             B2 = closest_point(C,D,B)
             C2 = closest_point(A,B,C)
             B2 = closest_point(A,B,D)
             if A2 == B2:
                 return math.sqrt(distance_squared(closest_point(C,D,A2)),A2)
             if C2 == D2:
                 return math.sqrt(distance_squared(closest_point(A,B,C2)),C2)
             A = A2
             B = B2
             C = C2
             D = D2
             distances_squared= [distance_squared(A,B),
                      distance_squared(B,C),
                      distance_squared(A,D),
                      distance_squared(B,D)
                      ]
             if max(distances_squared)-min(distances_squared) < epsilon:
                 return math.sqrt(min(distances_squared))
     return math.sqrt(min(distances_squared))
```

Try that out on some sample cases and see how it goes.

Comment: oh boy I'll have to learn Python first

Comment: I was kind of looking for a mathematical formula I could implement on my own. Yes though, "if"'s are allowed.